# Open the html selected list with a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a  option list in a webpage where I want to open the select list with a button created with a `<div>` when a option selected from the list then the selected value comes on the div also.

So here I want the javascript attribute to open the list on button click something like this

```
document.getElementById('selectedlist').open.
```

any body have suggestion about this?

Comment: Here we can check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/yqfEF/1/) of kriangkrai answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/expandselect/. I think this is what you want.
Then you can open the select like this.

```
ExpandSelect("myselect_id")
```

Comment: look how that will work in a mobile browser (43% of clients), whilst many or all of the mobile webkit versions would do what the user initially wanted by simply focusing on the select.

Comment: @HarishKumar Can you show your code? After you include `ExpandSelect.js` into your page then you can just open the select when button is clicked like this. `<input type="button" value="open select" onclick="ExpandSelect('selectedlist');" />`

Comment: here my code i have used
    <div class="fake_list" id="fake_list" onclick="ExpandSelect('category')">All Stores &Darr;</div>
category is the id of the select list.

Comment: @ Kriangkrai Bumroungruksa oh yes sorry it got worked i have changed the id that time. thanks a lot

Comment: @HarishKumar You're welcome. If you think this approach solve your problem, please mark it as accepted answer by press on the check mark. And you may consider to accept your other questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple Javascript code to open(toggle) the select box on clicking the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function expandSelect(id){
    var select_flag = document.getElementById('select_flag').value;
        if(select_flag==1){
            var select_box = document.getElementById(id);
            select_box.size = 1;
            document.getElementById('select_flag').value = 0;
        }else{
            var select_box = document.getElementById(id);
            select_box.size = select_box.options.length; 
            document.getElementById('select_flag').value = 1;
        }
   }
</script>

<button onclick="expandSelect('select_box')"> Toggle Select Box </button>


<div id="container">
    <select name="select_box" id="select_box" >
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="">option1</option>
        <option value="">option2</option>
        <option value="">option3</option>
        <option value="">option4</option>
        <option value="">option5</option>
        <option value="">option6</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="select_flag" id="select_flag" value="0">
</div>
```